# when validate master page login form on content page, content page fields also get validating

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have used **jquery validation on pop up login** which is placed in master page and also i did the validation as in below link on content page for registering new user.

But the problem is when i am in sign up page i cant login through the pop up, the sign up page fields also get validated please give me a solution for this.

I have follow these step.

```
my master page form tag is 

 <form runat="server" id="form1" novalidate>

--------content place holder-------

</form>
```

**Popup have these fields:**

```
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
 <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername" CssClass="control-label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Email %>"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" TextMode="Email" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" data-msg=" " data-msg-email=" "  required="required" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>
                     <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
  <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" CssClass="control-label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Password %>"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"runat="server"CssClass="form-control" data-msg=" " required="required" Text="" </asp:TextBox>
                            </div>       
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRememberMe"runat="server" />

 <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource,RememberMe %>" ></asp:Literal>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                <asp:ButtonID="btnSignIn"runat="server"OnClick="btnSignIn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"  Text="<%$Resources:Resource,SignIn %>"/>  <%--ValidationGroup="masterValidation"--%>


                            </div>
```

**Master page validation script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#form1").validate({
                  rules: {
                      "<%=txtUsername.UniqueID%>": {
                          required: true,
                          email:true
                    },
                   " <%=txtPassword.UniqueID%>": {                       

                      required: true
                     }
                }, messages: {
                    "<%=txtUsername.UniqueID%>":{
                        required: " Please enter valid email "

                    },
                    "<%=txtPassword.UniqueID%>": {

                        required: "Please enter valid password "
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please give me a solution guys,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your master page property will be shared between your content page

your master page form id is Form1

```
<form runat="server" id="form1" novalidate>

--------content place holder-------

</form>
```

and you are validating like

```
$("#form1").validate
```

so the content page will be also validated so try to check again and do something different

Comment: but how i validate only the login fields i have chaged the selector as id of the model but there is no validation occurs please give solution

Comment: i know that form 1 is in master page so that its validate for all the pages but how can i seperately validate the sign up page n login pop up please help me